# MySQL Compare Columns from Two Tables AND WHERE X = "%%"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query to compare columns from two tables and add in a WHEREs for other criteria.

I hope the example of what I'm trying to do will help.

```
SELECT `practice-name`, `practice-address-4`, `practice-address-5`, `practice-bnf-name` 
FROM `practice-information` 
JOIN `practice-prescribing` 
WHERE `practice-information.practice-number` = `practice-prescribing.practice-number` AND 
      `practice-name` LIKE "%%" OR `practice-address-4` LIKE "%%" OR
      `practice-address-5` LIKE "%%" OR `practice-bnf-name` LIKE "%%" 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: How do I go about doing what I've tried to explain with the example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What about a trigger /procedure ? Maybe this could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133876/compare-stored-procedures-across-multiple-databases-sql-server  but notice that this one is for databases and not tables.

Comment: Some sample input data along with expected result set would help us understand better what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Gravy got the closest to what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    `practice-name`, 
    `practice-address-4`, 
    `practice-address-5`, 
    `practice-bnf-name` 
FROM `practice-information` 
JOIN `practice-prescribing` ON `practice-information`.`practice-number` = `practice-prescribing`.`practice-number`
WHERE 
    `practice-name` LIKE "%PUT STUFF HERE%" OR 
    `practice-address-4` LIKE "%PUT STUFF HERE%" OR
    `practice-address-5` LIKE "%PUT STUFF HERE%" OR 
    `practice-bnf-name` LIKE "%PUT STUFF HERE%" 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'practice-information.practice-number' in 'on clause'

Comment: Apologies - was a typo, either remove the backticks, or separate table from column. see updated answer

Comment: apologies once again - use the second version. With the backticks. Because the `-` means minus in mysql.